# How to create methods like sorted() that takes the receiver as a parameter in swift?

Tags: swift, parameters, cgrect

I wrote an extension to CGRect class. I added a method which scales the CGRect by a factor. However i don't know how to write it so that I could achieve something like

```
    let newFrame = view.frame.scale(by: 0.8)
```

and it returns a CGRect to be set to newFrame.

What I have tried so far..

```
func scale(_ input: CGRect, byFactor factor: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    let newCentre = input.centre
    let newHeight = input.size.height * factor
    let newWidth = input.size.width * factor
    let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
    let newRect = CGRect(centre: newCentre, size: newSize)
    return newRect
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Edit:

```
var upperLeft: CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: minX, y: minY) }
var centre: CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: upperLeft.x + size.width/2, y: upperLeft.y + size.height/2) }

init(centre: CGPoint, size: CGSize) {
    let upperLeft = CGPoint(x: centre.x-size.width/2, y: centre.y-size.height/2)
    self.init(origin: upperLeft, size: size)
}
```

What I implemented in the extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The receiver in an extension of a class, struct or enum is represented by `self`

```
extension CGRect {

  func scale(byFactor factor: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    let newCentre = self.centre
    let newHeight = self.height * factor // CGRect has width and height properties
    let newWidth = self.width * factor
    let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
    let newRect = CGRect(centre: newCentre, size: newSize)
    return newRect
  }
}
```

PS: A simpler implementation of `centre` is

```
var centre : CGPoint  {
   return CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self), y:CGRectGetMidY(self))
}
```

Comment: CGRect has no member centre

Comment: @Igor, Yes, I noticed that, but I assume the OP has added the property (as well as the initializer) in the extension.

Comment: hi Igor, the centre property is also in my extension

Comment: @vadian, you must add this property to your answer for another users, otherwise code is wrong.

Comment: @Igor I just added my implementations of centre and initialisers

Comment: @MinhaoDong I added a simpler implementation of `centre`, `upperLeft` is not needed.

Comment: @vadian thank you, I need the upperLeft in my code but your centre implementation is still better!   Edit: just realised upperLeft is actually the origin..

Answer (score 0):

Extension of CGRect to scale rect with the same centre:

```
extension CGRect {
    mutating func scale(factor: CGFloat) {
        let newHeight = self.size.height * factor
        let newWidth = self.size.width * factor
        let newX = self.origin.x + (self.height - newHeight) / 2
        let newY = self.origin.y + (self.width - newWidth) / 2
        self = CGRect(x: newX, y: newY, width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
    }
}
```

usage:

```
view.frame.scale(0.8)
```

Comment: I think this more easy solution